# JWT + Axios React request doesn't pass access control

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, jwt

I'm using ReactJS + Axios to authenticate with JWT.

Tested on Postman Works:

- username:
- password:

then get:

- access_token
- token_expiration <3600>
- token_type

But on my ReactJS application do not work. Which means is my code.

For a reason I can't understand (SORRY!) I'm getting the error:

**Console**:

```
    Access to fetch at 'https://api.<URL>.com/auth/token' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:
 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque 
response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS 
disabled.
    fetch-wrapper.js:23          POST https://api.<URL>.com/auth/token net::ERR_FAILED
```

**Network:**

```
Request URL: https://api.<URL>.com/auth/token
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Provisional headers are shown
Learn more
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
access_token_expires_in: 3600
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
sec-ch-ua: "Not_A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="109", "Chromium";v="109"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
token_type: Bearer
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

**fetch_wrapper.js**

```
    import { store, authActions } from '_store';
    
    export const fetchWrapper = {
        get: request('GET'),
        post: request('POST'),
        put: request('PUT'),
        delete: request('DELETE')
    };
    
    function request(method) {
        return (url, body) => {
            const requestOptions = {
                method,
                headers: authHeader(url)
            };
            if (body) {
                requestOptions.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
// I commented and uncommented these 3 lines too
                requestOptions.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
                requestOptions.headers['access_token_expires_in'] = 3600;
                requestOptions.headers['token_type'] = "Bearer";
                requestOptions.body = JSON.stringify(body);
            }
            return fetch(url, requestOptions).then(handleResponse);
        }
    }
    
    // helper functions
    
    function authHeader(url) {
        // return auth header with jwt if user is logged in and request is to the api url
        const token = authToken();
        const isLoggedIn = !!token;
        const isApiUrl = url.startsWith(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL);
        if (isLoggedIn && isApiUrl) {
            return { 
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                access_token: `${token}`
            }
                ;
        } else {
            return {};
        }
    }
    
    function authToken() {
        return store.getState().auth.user?.token;
    }
    
    function handleResponse(response) {
        return response.text().then(text => {
            const data = text && JSON.parse(text);
    
            if (!response.ok) {
                if ([401, 403].includes(response.status) && authToken()) {
                    // auto logout if 401 Unauthorized or 403 Forbidden response returned from api
                    const logout = () => store.dispatch(authActions.logout());
                    logout();
                }
    
                const error = (data && data.message) || response.statusText;
                return Promise.reject(error);
            }
    
            return data;
        });
    }
```

**auth.slice.js**

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

import { history, fetchWrapper } from '_helpers';

// create slice

const name = 'auth';
const initialState = createInitialState();
const reducers = createReducers();
const extraActions = createExtraActions();
const extraReducers = createExtraReducers();
const slice = createSlice({ name, initialState, reducers, extraReducers });

// exports

export const authActions = { ...slice.actions, ...extraActions };
export const authReducer = slice.reducer;

// implementation

function createInitialState() {
    return {
        // initialize state from local storage to enable user to stay logged in
        user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')),
        error: null
    }
}

function createReducers() {
    return {
        logout
    };

    function logout(state) {
        state.user = null;
        localStorage.removeItem('user');
        history.navigate('/login');
    }
}

function createExtraActions() {
    // const baseUrl = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/users`;
    const baseUrl = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}`;

    return {
        login: login()
    };    

    function login() {
        return createAsyncThunk(
            `${name}/login`,
            async ({ username, password }) => await fetchWrapper.post(`${baseUrl}/auth/token`, { username, password })
            // async ({ username, password }) => await fetchWrapper.post(`${baseUrl}/authenticate`, { username, password })

        );
    }
}

function createExtraReducers() {
    return {
        ...login()
    };

    function login() {
        var { pending, fulfilled, rejected } = extraActions.login;
        return {
            [pending]: (state) => {
                state.error = null;
            },
            [fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
                const user = action.payload;
                
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
                state.user = user;

                // get return url from location state or default to home page
                const { from } = history.location.state || { from: { pathname: '/' } };
                history.navigate(from);
            },
            [rejected]: (state, action) => {
                state.error = action.error;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Could you help me, please? I'm really struggling to solve this issue that I can't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With CORS, the server is allowed to specify which cross-origin
> requests it will accept vs reject. It can reject requests that need
> cookies. It can reject requests from untrusted.mybank.com but accept
> requests from app.mybank.com. It can reject all POST requests but
> allow GETs and PUTs.

If you get an CORS restriction for your dev environment (ex: localhost:3000) is probably a server restriction and not just a header request.

Check with the backend/server side.